# make file system accessible again

Tags: 22.04, mountpoint

I'm new to linux, I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 replacing Windows OS.
In Windows I had 4 drives,
`C`, `D`, `E`, `F`
I have my files on drives `E` and `F`

while installing Linux,
I formatted and choose C drive as '`/`'
and `D` drive as '`/home`',
and kept `E` and `F` as `ntfs` file system and mounted as '`/home/files`'
and '`/home/videos`' respectively.

Now I able to access the files in `E` and `F` after installation, but unable to modify them.
and files are in `root` user,
is there anyway that I can make those drives writable(modifiable) and change their ownership?

```
UUID=   /               ext2    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda4 during installation
UUID= /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# /home/projects was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID= /home/projects  ntfs    defaults,umask=007,gid=46 0       0
# /home/videos was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID= /home/videos    ntfs    defaults,umask=007,gid=46 0       0
# swap was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID= none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use chown to assign your user name as owner.

```
sudo chown -R USERNAME:GROUPNAME /PATH
```

From chown help:

> -R, --recursive        operate on files and directories recursively

N.B. Your group name usually is the same as your username

Comment: still unable to modify
`chown: changing ownership of '/home/videos/': Read-only file system`

Comment: You need to run the command with sudo. I edited my previous reply to show that.

Comment: yes, I ran the command with sudo permission

Comment: Ok. We have tow options here: One, make sure the files for writing NTFS partion is installed using `sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g` Two, remove any log files left from windows with `sudo ntfsfix /dev/sd??` (replace the ?? with your drive name and number, ex. sda3, sdb4 ...etc

Comment: I did `sudo ntfsfix /dev/sd5` and this command `sudo ntfsfix /dev/sd` now I'm able to modify the files, but sitll unable to change ownership

Comment: It is good you can modify the files. Let's see your mount options using `sudo nano /etc/fstab`

Comment: If you no longer have Windows then you SHOULDN'T keep NTFS partitions around. There will be a time when you need to error correct those and that CAN'T be done from Linux (it requires Windows tools). So, do yourself a favor and backup the files to somewhere else and then use Disks to remove those partitions, create a new one or more (keep in mind over-partitioning is usually a mistake) and format as EXT4.

Comment: @UsamaFoad I've updated the output of the cmd `sudo nano /etc/fstab` above

Comment: @ChanganAuto some of my friends suggested me, if in future, if I want to transfer or share files to a windows machine, NTFS will be good. so I kept it that way. for my `/home` dir partition, I've used `ext4` file system

Comment: Correct suggestion if it's an external drive -and- you have access to Windows. Obviously NOT the case here.